# Untied variable from DOM object

Tags: javascript, html

Let suppose we have:

`Let myVar = document.getElementbyId("Sample")`

How can I process/modify the value in the javascript variable `myVar` without affecting anymore the DOM object?

Anytime I do something like:
`myVar.value = myVar.value + 100;`  The DOM is altered too, since myVar is representing the DOM object, instead of only have caught its value.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(ev) {
  var a = document.getElementById("myInput")
  var b = a
  b.value = "Why DOM changed?";
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <label>Original input value </label>
  <br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="55"/>
<button id="btn">Modify Variable - NOT DOM Obj</button>
</html>
```

Comment: *Anytime I do something like: `myVar2 = myVar + 100;` The DOM is altered too, since myVar is representing the DOM object, instead of only have caught its value.* - No, **it's the exact opposite.** `myVar` isn't even a DOM object - it's just the value of the DOM object, a primitive...

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: It still won't happen the way you say. Is it possible you wrote `myVar.value += 100`? That assigns back to the `.value` property.

Comment: Still incorrect. The DOM isn't altered at all.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to put executable HTML and JS in the question.

Comment: It *still* isn't correct. `myVar` contains the value of an input field, i.e. a **string**. Strings don't have a `value` property.

Comment: @Barmar Please, check the snippet.

Comment: Solved, check my answer.

Comment: This is very different from your original question, where you said you were assigning to the variable, not to a property of the object in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that any variable in Javascript which is assigned to an array or object (Such as DOM elements) **just reference to the original array or object, not having an independent value**.

That's why any changes I did to `Myvar` affected the DOM.  What I did to solve the issue is to **clone** the object into a variable.  I did it using a underscore function:

`myVar = ._clone(document.getElementbyId("Sample"))`

Now I can manipulate myVar without affecting the DOM.
I found the answer here:
[Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN on HTMLInputElement:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

> value: string: Returns / Sets the current value of the control.

It's simple. **If you don't want to modify the DOM, then don't *set* the `value` attribute of your HTMLInputElement**. Instead, save it to another variable and modify it afterwards.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.value = myInput.value + 100; // this is where the "issue" exists

// instead...
var inputValue = myInput.value;
inputValue = inputValue + 100; // DOM does not reflect the change
```

Comment: You are right.  Perhaps, what I'm trying to do is to get a copy of the DOM object in a variable and modify some attributes of it keeping the object structure inside the var.   No matter how many pivot variables I use, the DOM still affected.

Comment: It's because they are by reference. In your update, `b` is pointing to the same element that `a` is.

Comment: I know, my point is: There is a way to catch the object in an "independent" variable not tied to the DOM?  I only need to modify the object structure for other template, not the current one.

Comment: Got it. I've been looking it up myself since I don't know the answer. If I find a way I'll be sure to update my answer!

Comment: Solved, check my answer.  Thanks for your help.